# How to create stripe token using @stripe/stripe-react-native library

Tags: android, ios, react-native, stripe-payments

I was using tipsi-stripe library but now i migrated it to @stripe/stripe-react-native library  but i am unable to create token and get country name from card , please let me know how to implement it ,Thanks in advance.

------------------ Tipsi-stripe Code ----------------

```
import stripe, { PaymentCardTextField, } from 'tipsi-stripe'
stripe
                        .paymentRequestWithCardForm()
                        .then(stripeTokenInfo => {
                            this.state.loading = true
                            console.log('Token created', { stripeTokenInfo });
```

-------------- New Code without Create token ---------------------

```
import { CardField, useStripe ,confirmPayment, loading} from '@stripe/stripe-react-native';

export default class CheckoutSignin extends Component {
  state = {
    TotalAmount:null,
    clientSecret:null
  }
componentDidMount(){
  console.log("Total Amount : " + this.props.route.params.TotalAmount);
  this.state.TotalAmount = this.props.route.params.TotalAmount;
  this.setState(this.state)
}
 fetchPaymentIntentClientSecret = async () => {
        
  makePayment(100,"AUD").then(r => {
      if(r.Status === "Success"){

        this.state.clientSecret = r.ClientSecret;
        this.setState(this.state)
          // alert("Payment Indent Success");
          // console.log("1===> "+ clientSecret);
          this.handlePayPress();
          // console.log("3===> "+ clientSecret);
      }
      else {

          alert("Payment Indent Failed.");
      }
     
  }).catch(e => {
      alert(e)
  })

};


 handlePayPress = async () => {
 
  const {paymentIntent, error} = await confirmPayment(this.state.clientSecret, {
  paymentMethodType: 'Card',
  paymentMethodData: {
    // email: _userInfo.email,
  },
});
if (error) {
  console.log('Payment confirmation error', error);
  Alert.alert("Error","Payment confirmation error", error);
} else if (paymentIntent) {
  console.log('Success from promise', paymentIntent);
  // Alert.alert("Success","Succeed Payment with 3ds");
  this.props.navigation.navigate("Thankyou")
}

 } 
}
```

Comment: You would not create a token anymore as that's a legacy approach, instead you can access the details of the card used after the payment while handling the webhook for the successful payment on your backend server. https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=react-native&ui=payment-sheet#react-native-fulfillment

Comment: @karllekko, Thanks for your answer but I need Country Name from card before payment because I have to use condition for 3ds allow only to some countries, please help.